# WSPBuilder in Visual Studio 2010 for solution in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, wspbuilder

I've installed the WSPBuilder extension for Visual Studio 2010 and I'm looking for a walkthrough of how to create a deployment package for my web-part.  Can anyone point me to a good resource?  Everything I find seems to be directed towards VS 2008 and it creates the folder structure differently.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious... why do you want to use WSPBuilder? I haven't found a situation yet that I couldn't use VS2010's built-in packaging functionality (for both SP 2007 and 2010 solutions).

Comment: I was told it was the easiest way to create an installation package for a feature.  I did it manually for an event handler, but I it's a different procedure for web-parts.  I compiled the code to a DLL, used the makecab command to create the WSP and then installed it on the server with that WSP.  What would you suggest?  What's this VS2010 packaging functionality you speak of that doesn't include the usage of WSPBuilder?

Comment: If you're using VS2010 on the same machine as a SharePoint 2010 instance (it's installable on Win7 x64), you've got everything you need to package a SharePoint solution in a WSP. No third-party tools needed!

Comment: I wish it were that simple.  I'm developing for Sharepoint 2007 on a different machine that doesn't have Sharepoint but has Visual Studio 2010.  I have Visual Studio 2008 on the Sharepoint machine, however when I go to create a WSPBuilder project, I get this error which I couldn't figure out: "The profile for the user is a temporary profile"

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 has the ability to package web part projects. Just be sure to get the [Visual Studio Extensions for SharePoint Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=FB9D4B85-DA2A-432E-91FB-D505199C49F6).

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you have found already should be close enough - the hive folder is named "SharePointRoot" instead of "12", but aside from that it's all the same for basic usage.

Developing for SharePoint without having SharePoint on the dev box is going to be fairly painful whatever method you use though. I have a PowerShell script that deploys a WSP on another server so I can use the same development environment for 2007 and 2010 - it works but is a lot slower than the local copy to GAC or hive when making small changes. The error you are getting with VS2008 can probably be fixed by running visual studio as administrator.